# Infinite Loop for jTicker plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a jQuery effect that type simple text out like a typewrite or if you were manually typing it. I need the effect to wait a few seconds, delete all that text and then retype it out. So I want it to create an "infinite" looping effect.

This is the code I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" SRC="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" SRC="js/jquery.jticker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // Instantiate jTicker 
    jQuery("#ticker").ticker({
        cursorList:  "|",
        rate:        150,
        delay:       4000
    }).trigger("play").trigger("stop");
});
//-->
</script>
<div id="ticker">
    <p>typed out text...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: plugin likely needs modification

Comment: which `jquery.jticker.js` are you using? please provide the link...

Comment: Plugin likely needs identification and brought up to jQuery 1.8

Comment: Isn't there a way I can just repeat the entire thing?

Comment: http://www.thepixelart.com/create-a-typing-text-effect-using-jquery/

Comment: I am open to a simple alternative. But it must type out like that, get deleted and retyped infinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
var delayMilliSecs = 4000;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var tickerSelector = $("#ticker p");
    var originalLength = tickerSelector.length;
    RunTicker();
    window.setInterval(function() {
        if (tickerSelector.length === originalLength) {
            RunTicker();
        }
    }, delayMilliSecs);
});

function RunTicker() {
    jQuery("#ticker").ticker({
        cursorList: "|",
        rate: 150,
        delay: delayMilliSecs
    }).trigger("play").trigger("stop");
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/codovations/jNtqa/

Comment: Very nice! This is exactly what I was looking for. Is there a way to delete each character one by one or will that require a lot more jQuery/Plugins/Work?

Answer (score 0):

I used a simple solution for this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var repeat_interval = 10000;

    // Instantiate jTicker 
    jQuery("#ticker").ticker({
        cursorList:  " ",
        rate:        70,
        delay:       100,
    }).trigger("play").trigger("stop");


    setInterval(function(){ jQuery("#ticker").trigger("play") },repeat_interval);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
}).trigger("play").trigger("stop");
```

For:

```
}).trigger({type: "play"});
```